# Angular Unit Testing - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size') NgRx

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ngrx

I get an error about my spec file unit test without success to solve, the error display when I run `npm test`, on `karma chrome`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5gsJ.png)

agent.service.spec.ts:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MemoizedSelector, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import * as fromGrid from './../grid/store/grid.reducer';

import { GridActions } from './../grid/store/grid.actions';
import { AgentService } from './agent.service';
import { GridSizeEnum } from '../models/enums/GridSize';


describe('AgentService', () => {

    let agentService: AgentService;
    let mockStore: MockStore<fromGrid.State>;
    let mockGridSizeSelector: MemoizedSelector<fromGrid.State, GridSizeEnum>;
    let size: GridSizeEnum = GridSizeEnum.GRID_1


    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                RouterTestingModule
            ],
            providers: [
                AgentService,
                provideMockStore({}),

            ],
        });

        agentService = TestBed.get(AgentService);
        mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);
        mockGridSizeSelector = mockStore.overrideSelector(fromGrid.getGridSize, size);
    });

    it('should return the default state', () => {

        const action = {} as GridActions;
        const state = fromGrid.reducer(fromGrid.initialState, action);
        expect(state).toBe(fromGrid.initialState);

    });

    it('should be created', () => {

        expect(agentService).toBeTruthy();
    });

    afterEach(() => {

    })


});
```

agent.service.ts :

the constructor part-

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private gridStore: Store<fromGrid.State>,
    private commandWebSocket: CommandWebsocketService,
    private logService: LogService) {

    this.commandWebSocket.connect();
    this.commandWebSocket.messages$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.commandWebsocketData(data);
    });

    this.store.pipe(select(fromGrid.getGridSize), takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((size) => {
      if (size) {
        this.gridSize = size;
      }
    });

    this.gridStore.pipe(select(fromGrid.getGridVideoStreamIDs, this.gridSize), takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe(data => {
      if (data && data.length) {
        this.gridStreamIDs = data;
        const byPassCpuIdsCopy = this.byPassCpuIds;
        this.byPassCpuIds = [];
        this.gridStreamIDs.filter((dta) => {
          this.byPassCpuIds[dta] = byPassCpuIdsCopy[dta];
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

grid.reducer.ts :

```
export const getGridSize = createSelector(
  getGridFeatureState,
  state => state.size
);
```

This error appears a lot in another case, when I have subscribe to specific selector at `constructor()` or at `ngOnInit()`  (if it component unit test ).

For solution i tried to initial the state in spec file, see above in `agent.service.spec`... but it isn't solved.
Need your help, thanks!

How can i solve this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'size')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your store:

```
provideMockStore({
  grid: {     // assuming 'grid' is your feature key
    size: 5
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Besides the initial state in provideMockStore(),  also needs to provide the specific selector

Comment: This should actually work without overriding the selector if the supplied state is in the correct format. Alternatively you can override the selector like in your answer but specify only an empty object for the state as the overridden selector will never access it.

Answer (score 0):

also need to initialize the selectors in  `provideMockStore()`:

```
provideMockStore({
     initialState: fromGrid.initialState,
     selectors: [
         {
            selector: fromGrid.getGridSize,
            value: GridSizeEnum.GRID_1
         }
     ]
 }),
```